# CSS toggler using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to toggle the white-space style of a `tr` element to normal when the `tr` is clicked. I've managed to take a function used for toggling colours and adapt this for my purposes, however I can only make the class change toggle once, and don't know how to change the `this.style.background` in line 3 to `this.style.white-space`, without breaking everything:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('tr').click(function () {
        if(this.style.background == "" || this.style.background =="white") {
            $(this).css('white-space', 'normal');
        }
        else {
            $(this).css('white-space', 'nowrap');
        }
    });
});
```

I know this is fairly basic, however I've only started using JavaScript today, so if anyone could show me the solution and explain what needs to be done then I'd be very appreciative.

Comment: Could you please share the HTML?

Comment: It is not recommended to toggle inline styles, instead create a class and toggle it, and you only need this one line in your click event, e.g. `$( this ).toggleClass( "whitespace-nowrap" );`

Comment: Thankyou, I was going to get round to that at some point so thanks for giving me the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change the `if` condition so it depends on the value of `white-space` property:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('tr').click(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        if($this.css('white-space') === 'nowrap') {
            $this.css('white-space', 'normal');
        }
        else {
            $this.css('white-space', 'nowrap');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thankyou, this works. Can I just verify how I think this is working:

If the tr is clicked, and the white-space == nowrap, then change to normal, else if the white-space == normal, change to nowrap?

Comment: Thankyou. Several more questions, what is 'this' referring to, the current object? And can you explain the var $this = $(this) line please.

Comment: `this` refers to current `tr` element that was clicked (regular `dom object`).   

`$(this)` wraps the `tr` element into `jQuery object`, so we can use handy functions like `.css(..)`.   

`var $this = $(this)` we store the `jQuery object` into variable `$this` so we dont have to call jQuery constructor (`$(this)`) 3 times in the code below (so basically, its a bit cleaner, and more performant).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I don't quite understand the second part but I'm sure that will come in time. Thanks again, I know this was probably very basic!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use `white-space` for your `if`statements, and refactor those `if` statements. Fixed code below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('tr').click(function () {
        if($(this).css("white-space") == "nowrap") {
            $(this).css('white-space', 'normal');
        }
        else {
            $(this).css('white-space', 'nowrap');
        }
    });
});
```

Hopefully this helps!